# How can I modify input variables with string modifiers in zsh?

Tags: zsh, user-input

I've been working on a `bold` function as a proof-of-concept and a challenge to myself. I am trying to input text (e.g.`foo`) and have it print to standard output as it's bold counterpart (**`foo`**).

Context:

I've been using `echo` and basing it off of my `PROMPT` variable in my theme file. I am not using any frameworks.

The theme uses codes like `%B%n%b` to bold the username (`%n`), but I don't know how to replace that `%n` with user input (`$1`). Any Help?

Edit: Attempted Code

```
echo '%B'"$1"'%b'
```

-tried with and without quotes in various locations, as well as with sub-shell (`{}`)

Comment: curly brackets `{}` just group commands, they don't create subshells.

Answer (score 1):

`%B` and `%b` are examples of [prompt sequences](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), and usually can only be used for formatting prompts. For normal scripting, you can use the `tput` command to achieve what you want:

```
echo "$(tput bold)$1$(tput sgr0)"
```

Alternatively, you could output the [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) ("ANSI") escape codes directly. I wouldn't recommend this though, because it's less portable across terminals.  (It's quite hard, nowadays in the 21st century, to encounter a terminal that doesn't implement ECMA-48 and the basic ECMA-48 SGR features like boldface, but since you are challenging yourself to learn this, you should learn that terminals do not have the guarantee of understanding exactly the same control sequences as one another.  You should also learn that there still remain a few terminal emulators where boldface is a colour change and not a font weight change.)

```
echo $'\e[1m'"$1"$'\e[22m'
```

Notice the use of [Korn-style quoting](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting) for the control sequences.
In the general case, the `echo` command may or may not *itself* interpret `\e` sequences if not Korn-style quoted and such escape sequences work differently in different shells, or even different versions of the same shell; and conversely not all shells understand Korn-style quoting.
See "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/162898)" for the whole tale and why `echo` is not a good idea if you are addressing anything other than a single specific (version of a) shell.

```
printf '\e[1m%s\e[22m' "$1"
```

Notice that SGR 0 (corresponding to `\e[0m`, which is what `tput sgr0` also usually nowadays emits) turns off *everything*, which may not be what you want if you are *also* using underlining, italics, colours, reverse video, or other graphic renditions.
To turn off boldface *specifically*, SGR 22 is the graphic rendition code, which turns off boldface and faint, restoring "medium" font weight.  (The **S**et **G**raphic **R**endition control sequence lets you set four font weights: bold, demibold, medium, and light.)

Since you *are* using the Z shell, you can *also* use [its own built-in `print` command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print) instead of using `echo` or `printf` at all.
The built-in `print` can be told to understand Z shell prompt expansion sequences:

```
print -P '%B'"$1"'%b'
```

Of course, your `$1` string must not contain other expansion sequences itself, nor indeed any SGR control sequences for changing boldface.
And this won't give you the challenge of learning `tput` and how terminfo capabilities work.

Comment: That has its own interface to terminfo with the `echoti` builtin (inspired from tcsh's `echotc`) and the `$terminfo` special associative array.

Answer (score 1):

`%` parameter expansion flag can be used:

```bsh
echo "${(%):-%B}$1${(%):-%b}"
```

---

zsh has a `print` builtin which has `-P` to perform prompt expansions (Note: if $1 contains prompt sequences, they will be interpreted as such):

```bsh
print -P -- "%B$1%b"
```

---

You may want to print all arguments instead of just the first positional parameter (use `$@`/`$*`).

You may want to print nothing (not even a newline) if no parameters were given (print only if `$#` is greater than zero, or use `+` parameter expansion & tell `print` to output columns).

You may want to disable echo-like interpretation of backslash escapes (`print -r`).

```bsh
print_bold() {
  local IFS=' '
  print -rC1 -- ${1+"${(%):-%B}$*${(%):-%b}"}
}
```

`"$*"` expands to positional parameters separated by first character of `IFS` (which is a space by default, but has been set explicitly above).

Comment: See also `${(j[ ])*}` to explicitly join on SPC without having to rely on `$IFS`.